# Why can you access an image on server directly but need to use AJAX for other file types?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, file, file-io

Why is it that in JavaScript you can get direct access to an image on the server just by specifying its url, e.g. by doing:

```
myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = "xxx.jpg";
```

But in order to read for example a binary file you would have to make an AJAX request to access it?
What's the difference, exactly? Web programming continues to be a mystery to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain types of files have native handlers in the form of HTML elements or JS constructors that intrinsically know what to do with those types of files.

An image is one such example. By specifying it as the `src` attribute of an HTML `<img />` tag or as the `src` property of a JS `Image` instance, you are implicitly feeding it to a mechanism that knows what to do with the image's source code.

This is not the case, say, for a text file. There is no HTML element or JS constructor associated with the loading and interpretation of text files. That is not to say you can't make the request. The following, though nonsensical, will nonetheless make a successful request:

```
<img src='some/text/file.txt' />
```

Rather, to meaningfully use the response, you will need AJAX, since HTML/JavaScript couldn't possibly hope to know, natively, what you intend to do with that response.

[EDIT]

Furthermore, as Djizeus makes clear in the comment below, images loaded into `<img />` elements or `Image` constructors do not give you access to their source code - they are merely output as image data to the page.

Comment: Correct, and I would even add: Javascript does *NOT* give you access to the image (or script or css file, etc), it only lets you ask the browser to handle it. But if you do want to access to the raw image file, you will need an AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

Any resource that HTML provides a native means to reference (images, scripts, stylesheets, video, audio, anything that can appear in an iframe, etc) doesn't require the use of Ajax.

Ajax just makes the raw data in the HTTP response available to JavaScript so you use it when you want to process the data with JS instead of using the browser's native handling (or lack of native handling) of it.

Comment: you're gonna reach 300k today ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically, at the browser-side, PROCESS the data arriving from a website, you need Ajax. Otherwise, you don't need that at all - but of course, some types of data may not "show" very well on the browser - all depends on what data it is.

JavaScript also has some builtin functions, for example, to handle images - it will then perform the "ajax" style requests inside the JS engine, rather than you having to do it manually. Ajax is a more generic method to access arbitrary data (including passing your own data in the request to the server, so you get the data for John Smith that is logged in, for example)